# Почему происходит ошибка при установке Microsoft SQL Server 2022 "Указанная служба не может быть запущена"?

Tags: sql, windows, sql-server

```
  SQLTEMPDBLOGDIR:               <пусто>
  SQLTEMPDBLOGFILEGROWTH:        64
  SQLTEMPDBLOGFILESIZE:          8
  SQLUSERDBDIR:                  C:\Database
  SQLUSERDBLOGDIR:               <пусто>
  SUPPRESSPAIDEDITIONNOTICE:     false
  SUPPRESSPRIVACYSTATEMENTNOTICE: false
  TCPENABLED:                    0
  UIMODE:                        AutoAdvance
  UpdateEnabled:                 true
  UpdateSource:                  MU
  USEMICROSOFTUPDATE:            false
  USESQLRECOMMENDEDMEMORYLIMITS: false

  Configuration file:            C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\160\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20230914_081553\ConfigurationFile.ini

Detailed results:
  Feature:                       Полнотекстовый и семантический поиск
  Status:                        Сбой
  Reason for failure:            Возникла ошибка для одной из зависимостей компонента, вызвавшая сбой процесса его установки.
  Next Step:                     Устраните ошибку, пользуясь следующими сведениями, удалите компонент, а затем запустите установку еще раз.
  Component name:                Экземпляры служб ядра СУБД SQL Server
  Component error code:          0x80004005
  Error description:             Указанная служба не может быть запущена, так как отключена либо она сама, либо все связанные с ней устройства.
  Error help link:               https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=16.0.1000.6&EvtType=0xDC112D1C%400xDC80C325&EvtType=0xDC112D1C%400xDC80C325

  Feature:                       Службы машинного обучения и расширения языка
  Status:                        Сбой
  Reason for failure:            Возникла ошибка для одной из зависимостей компонента, вызвавшая сбой процесса его установки.
  Next Step:                     Устраните ошибку, пользуясь следующими сведениями, удалите компонент, а затем запустите установку еще раз.
  Component name:                Экземпляры служб ядра СУБД SQL Server
  Component error code:          0x80004005
  Error description:             Указанная служба не может быть запущена, так как отключена либо она сама, либо все связанные с ней устройства.
  Error help link:               https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=16.0.1000.6&EvtType=0xDC112D1C%400xDC80C325&EvtType=0xDC112D1C%400xDC80C325

  Feature:                       Службы ядра СУБД
  Status:                        Сбой
  Reason for failure:            Возникла ошибка при установке компонента.
  Next Step:                     Устраните ошибку, пользуясь следующими сведениями, удалите компонент, а затем запустите установку еще раз.
  Component name:                Экземпляры служб ядра СУБД SQL Server
  Component error code:          0x80004005
  Error description:             Указанная служба не может быть запущена, так как отключена либо она сама, либо все связанные с ней устройства.
  Error help link:               https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=16.0.1000.6&EvtType=0xDC112D1C%400xDC80C325&EvtType=0xDC112D1C%400xDC80C325

  Feature:                       Репликация SQL Server
  Status:                        Сбой
  Reason for failure:            Возникла ошибка для одной из зависимостей компонента, вызвавшая сбой процесса его установки.
  Next Step:                     Устраните ошибку, пользуясь следующими сведениями, удалите компонент, а затем запустите установку еще раз.
  Component name:                Экземпляры служб ядра СУБД SQL Server
  Component error code:          0x80004005
  Error description:             Указанная служба не может быть запущена, так как отключена либо она сама, либо все связанные с ней устройства.
  Error help link:               https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=16.0.1000.6&EvtType=0xDC112D1C%400xDC80C325&EvtType=0xDC112D1C%400xDC80C325

  Feature:                       Обозреватель SQL
  Status:                        Пройдено

  Feature:                       Модуль записи SQL
  Status:                        Пройдено

  Feature:                       Файлы поддержки программы установки
  Status:                        Пройдено

Rules with failures or warnings:

Global rules:
Предупреждение IsFirewallEnabled                Брандмауэр Windows включен. Чтобы обеспечить удаленный доступ, убедитесь, что открыты соответствующие порты. Сведения о портах, которые необходимо открыть для каждого из компонентов, см. в документации по правилам на странице https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2162127.

Rules report file:               C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\160\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20230914_081553\SystemConfigurationCheck_Report.htm
```

Comment: `Component error code: 0x80004005` - может говорить о кривости установленной у вас операционной системы, могу только предполагать, что у вас установлена сборка некого by дядявася. Так же это может быть связано с проблемами со стороны SMB, но это маловероятно, прочитать радикальное решение можно вот тут: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/558174/sql-server-2019-setup-error-0x80004005#:~:text=2021%2C%201%3A21-,%D0%98%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%2C,-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B0%20%D0%B2%D1%8B%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8